# Lifecycle exception when deploying example spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I am trying to understand the basic steps of how to  deploy a spring boot application. However, despite the fact that I do everything correctly, I can't deploy it on a tomcat server. The tomcat successfuly extracts my `war` archive but it gives the folloving below error:

```
11-Dec-2016 16:49:31.975 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/springrest]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@5a0050e9]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4842)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4974)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@57a81b37]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:708)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid END header (bad central directory offset)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid END header (bad central directory offset)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:110)
    ... 17 more

11-Dec-2016 16:49:31.976 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive /home/bora/Desktop/apache-tomcat-8.5.9/webapps/springrest.war
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/springrest]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I think the error is caused by a ZipException. But I don't understand why. I have followed [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging) and [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) guides as exactly as it written, but ...

Here is more files, maybe it will be useful:
pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.bora.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>springrest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- <build> <plugins> <plugin> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> </plugin> </plugins> </build> -->

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

And my Application class:
    package com.bora.rest;

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String hello() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

}
```

I compile and package my maven project by givin `mvn clean package` and coppy the `.war` file into my tomcat's webapps folder. Restart the tomcat, it extracts but the above error occurs. I have been searching for solution for about 2 hours, but ...

My tomcat version is 8.5.9. I am using Ubuntu 16.04. Environment variables:

```
$CATALINA_BASE: /home/bora/Desktop/apache-tomcat-8.5.9
$CATALINA_HOME: /home/bora/Desktop/apache-tomcat-8.5.9
$CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/bora/Desktop/apache-tomcat-8.5.9/temp
$JRE_HOME:        /home/bora/Applications/jdk1.8.0_111
$CLASSPATH:       /home/bora/Desktop/apache-tomcat-8.5.9/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/bora/Desktop/apache-tomcat-8.5.9/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

I have strong knowledge about java language, I develop android applications. However, I am totally stranger to Java EE technologies. If someone finds an answer, could you please tell me the answer like you telling a child?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring-Boot ist using Tomcat 7 as default. This should be the reason why you get an exception. If u want to use Tomcat 8.5.9 u have to set the Version in your pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <tomcat.version>8.5.9</tomcat.version>
</properties>
```

**EDIT**

Use the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` for building the app. So you cant be sure your app is builded correctly.

**EDIT 2**

Just annotate your class with `@SpringBootApplication` this is enough. your Dont need the other ones.

**EDIT 3**

After compiling your code with my mentioned changes it worket fine. So the issue must be your config. Clear your local maven-repository and redownload the libaries. That should work.

Comment: Hmm. I have added what you said but I still get the same exceptions.

Comment: Ah and change your annotation. See Edit 2

Comment: I hate to tell, but still same... thanks for your efforts though.

Comment: Must be a problem with you config. I copied your pom and java class into my IDE, made the change i mentioned in the pom and changed the annotation. After that i compiled it and tested it into a tromcat 8.5.9 server and it worked. Maybe delete your local Maven-Repository so that maven download the libs again. Your code and ist correct with the changed i mentioned

Comment: It is as you told. I was using the maven that comes with netbeans. I have uninstalled the netbeans, deleted the `.m2` folder in my home folder. After that, I have installed a fresh apache maven from its official website and did `mvn clean package` again and deployes, it worked. Thanks. If you can edit your answer I am going to tick it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the version conflict, please check compiled version and JVM of Tomcat version are same.

1. Pls check JAVA_HOME
2. Check the Tomcat version to build. Follow the link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html
3. Check the Java version to build: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html

Hope this help.

Comment: I am using Java 1.8. I think it should be fine. And tomcat 8.5.9 supports java 1.8.

Comment: can you check your java version with the comment: java -version?! if it is set with Java8, can you try to download the new Tomcat and retry?!